# Question on Convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is the last question on my real analysis final exam. I didn't get to spend much time on it. Hopefully I remember the problem correctly.

$\{a_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_{n\geq1}a_n$ converges. Let $b_n$ be the cardinality of the set $\{k\in N:a_k>\frac{1}{2^n}\}$. Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}b_n=0$.

My thought is since $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges and $\sum a_n$ converges, their terms need to be "comparable", but I don't know how to capture this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some positive sequence $(c_n)$ with limit $0$, and, for every $n$ and $m$, let $$A_m=\sum\limits_{k=m}^\infty a_k\qquad B_n=\{k\mid a_k\geqslant c_n\}$$ Then, $$A_m\geqslant\sum_{k=m}^\infty\mathbf 1_{k\in B_n}a_k\geqslant\sum_{k=m}^\infty\mathbf 1_{k\in B_n}c_n=c_n\cdot\#B_n\cap[m,\infty)$$ hence $$c_n\cdot\#B_n\leqslant c_n\cdot m+c_n\cdot\#B_n\cap[m,\infty)\leqslant c_n\cdot m+A_m$$ In the limit $n\to\infty$, one gets, for every fixed $m$, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\,c_n\cdot\#B_n\leqslant\limsup_{n\to\infty}\,(c_n\cdot m+A_m)=A_m$$ The series $\sum a_k$ converges hence $\inf\limits_mA_m=0$, thus, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\,c_n\cdot\#B_n=0$$ If $c_n=2^{-n}$ for every $n$, then $\#B_n=b_n$ hence we are done.

Comment: In the first chain of inequality, should it be $c_n\cdot\#B_n\cap[m,\infty)$?

Comment: True! Well spotted, thanks.

Comment: Emmm, I'm still a bit confused about the last part. You first take n to infinity and then take m to infinity? But then why $#B_m = b_n$ ?

Comment: ?? $b_n=\#B_n$ **by definition**.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But the subscript is different? In the end you have c_n * #B_m not #B_n?

Comment: An obvious typo. Sure you cannot correct such points by yourself, simply by following the succession of inequalities?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just still confused with what you're doing. You find that lim cn * bn = Am. But then how do you conclude lim cn * bn = 0? Am is a variable and it's limit at infinity is 0. So we need to take m to infinity? Therefore I didn't know that was a typo.

Comment: Ahhh, my bad. lim cn * bn <= Am not = Am. Thank you for your patience and explanation! (My comment in latex doesn't show in formula form, so I decide to just type it like this. Excuse me.)